# How to turn off box class animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Box class get animated with piston class but i want it to stay in one position. I didn't know how he inherit this animation or why. I tried use (animation: none !important;) but it didn't work.

```css
@keyframes piston {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-top: 175px
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: 50px
  }
}

@keyframes handle {
  0%,
  100% {
    height: 225px
  }
  50% {
    height: 100px
  }
}

.piston {
  animation: piston 5s linear infinite;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -68px
}

.handle {
  animation: handle 5s linear infinite;
  width: 25px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-left: 68px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  width: 156px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='handle'>
  <div class='piston'></div>
</div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by putting the `div` with the `.box` class before the `div` with the `.handle` class in your HTML, and set the `.box` class to have `position: fixed` in your CSS.

Your animation positioning was slightly off, so I've fixed that for you as well. You can change the animation back and resize the height of the box to make it fit as well.

```css
@keyframes piston {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-top: 140px
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: 50px
  }
}

@keyframes handle {
  0%,
  100% {
    height: 175px
  }
  50% {
    height: 100px
  }
}

.piston {
  animation: piston 5s linear infinite;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -68px
}

.handle {
  animation: handle 5s linear infinite;
  width: 25px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-left: 68px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  width: 156px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  margin-left: 2px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='handle'>
  <div class='piston'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your animation using one element like below:

```css
.box {
  width: 156px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/25px 100% no-repeat;
  border-bottom:50px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:change 2s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change {
  from {
    transform:translateY(-60%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

Another idea with only background animation:

```css
.box {
  width: 156px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom center/25px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom /100% 50px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:content-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:change 2s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change {
  to {
    padding-bottom:120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, is there some way to mark problem as solved, in order to don't show it to people?

Comment: @Jirru I added another way if intrested